# CSS property top-margin don't show in firebug

Tags: css

### The case

I am making a single page website which uses  [One Page Navigation](https://github.com/davist11/jQuery-One-Page-Nav) jQuery plugin for smooth scrolling. The content is grouped into three pages:

1. **home.html**
2. **abilities.html**
3. **portfolio.html**

The idea is when a user is in home.html a jQuery function (js/pop4.js) loads the content of the other two pages in divs with the respective names:**#abilities-wrapper** and **#portfolio-wrapper**  and vice versa when in abilities.html the script loads the other two pages in current page.

I am also using a jQuery script which adds `possition:fixed,'top':0, 'left':0` to the menu after scrolling down and adding or removing `.hidden`  class to two other divs.

### The problem:

- I want the divs to have a margin-top: 120 px. I set this in the css file

**That is my css file:**

```
#home-wrapper{
margin-top:120 px;
}
#abilities-wrapper{
margin-top:120 px;
}
#portfolio-wrapper{
margin-top:120 px;
}
```

**This is what I get in Firebug:**

```
#home-wrapper{   
}
#abilities-wrapper{   
}
#portfolio-wrapper{    
}
```

#### The whole code is a bit long so:[you can see it here](http://boxofsand.org/current/home.html)

Comment: remove space between number and `px`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have a syntax error. Why you have white-space in between value and unit in which it is measured ? It should be like this:

```
#home-wrapper{
margin-top:120px;
}
#abilities-wrapper{
margin-top:120px;
}
#portfolio-wrapper{
margin-top:120px;
}
```

That `margin-top` property is not set as you have error in your code and hence, also not considered as a style of that div.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B5Hn3/)